# Next.js mongodb too many active connections

Tags: mongodb, next.js, caching

While development Using MongoClient from "mongodb" library on Next.js

seems that every time I reload the page(even hot-reloading on save) a new active connection with mongodb is created.

I'm caching a cachedClient so when few requests on same run happens it using the same connection but seems that every restart/exception a new active call is created and previous calls are not deleted(in the near time) by default.

What is the best practice for managing mongodb active client-connections?

mongodb.ts

```
export async function connectToDatabase(): Promise<{
  client: MongoClient;
  db: Db;
}> {
  if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
    return {
      client: cachedClient,
      db: cachedDb,
    };
  }
  const client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI);
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(MONGODB_DB);
  cachedClient = client;
  cachedDb = db;
  return {
    client: cachedClient,
    db: cachedDb,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you storing your `cachedClient` and `cachedDb` in the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) for development purposes. It would preserve your client upon hot reloading. You could also refer to the official NextJS example, they have this specific case covered already: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.ts

Additionally, if you want to specicy timeout for your MongoDB connections, you could pass a parameter specified here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#timeout-options

Comment: In additional to using a global client, look into the connection pool settings available in the connection string.